# Log.php returning 'Invalid User' from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am hosting a website from a local computer (using MAMP Pro on a Mac), and need to switch the hosting to another local Mac.  I have copied across all of the files for my website, and the MySQL tables, and checked that the server and MySQL are running OK.  Everything seems to be fine, except that the login system is returning "Invalid User" when I try to log in, even though I am entering the correct user info (I have tried a few users just to be sure).

The log.php that handles the login looks like this:

```
<?
session_name("MyLogin");
session_start();

if($_GET['action'] == "login") {
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password"); // your MySQL connection data
$db = mysql_select_db("nick"); //put your database name in here 
$name = $_POST['user'];
$q_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login='$name'");

if(mysql_num_rows($q_user) == 1) {

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login='$name'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($_POST['pwd'] == $data['password']) { 
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
header("Location: http://monthlymixup.com/may.php"); // success page. put the URL you want 
exit;
} else {
header("Location: login.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Wrong Password'));
exit;
}
} else {
header("Location: login.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Invalid User'));
exit;
}
}

// if the session is not registered
if(session_is_registered("name") == false) {
header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

I have temporarily removed the password in the above code.

I wonder what steps I can take to troubleshoot this issue, and would be grateful for any help.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: It's unrelated, but you ABSOLUTELY MUST use mysql_real_escape_string() on $name before using it in any SQL queries! Failing to do this will often allow a hacker to take over your website. See http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A few common techniques when I encounter this issue.

1. Output the generated SQL and test it by hand - `echo $query`;
2. See if `mysql_error()` outputs anything after you run your queries.
3. Use `var_dump()` and `print_r()` on your data objects to ensure they are as expected.
4. Comment out your redirects and `exit()` lines so you can determine where the script is breaking.

Fix or comment back with anything determined by the above.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I'm a bit slow when it comes to php, sorry about that.  So far I have looked in my mysql_error_log and nothing shows up when I try to run queries.  I am not sure where to include echo $query;  I tried including it in log.php and nothing different showed up

Comment: Put `echo "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login='$name'";` right after your `$name` assignment. Be sure this SQL runs.

Comment: This returns SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login=''  on the page

Comment: OK, so your bug is this line: `$name = $_POST['user'];`. Check the login form's `<input>` tag to make sure it has `name="user"`, and check the `<form>` tag has `method="post"`. You may also want to do print_r($_POST); to make sure it has a 'user' value in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does a query to find a user with the given username, and then checks if the number of rows with that username is exactly 1.

The only way you could see the 'Invalid User' error is if there are 0 users with that username or more than 1 user with that username.

Have a look at the contents of the table and check which of these is the case (I recommend http://sequelpro.com for viewing database contents on a Mac). You can also use sequel pro to test your queries.

Comment: Thanks. I have sequel pro installed. I can confirm that I have 70 users in the database, and none with duplicate names. I think the issue is with connecting to the database, but am not sure how to test it.  I can connect to the database to build a table on a webpage of the contents of a database table, using exactly the same username, password, etc